# Failed to create fake when default constructor for the object is not empty

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

I'm new to FakeItEasy, and I have a few test cases which are used to pass before (when I had no specific constructors defined). 
Then I have created a default constructor for one for the object I'm faking, the default constructor only create logger.

After I have created this constructor all my test cases are failing now, with following error, and I cannot figure out what it does not like or how to fix it:

```
FakeItEasy.Core.FakeCreationException : 
  Failed to create fake of type StorageService.
  Below is a list of reasons for failure per attempted constructor:
    No constructor arguments failed:
      No usable default constructor was found on the type StorageService.
      An exception of type System.NullReferenceException was caught during this call. Its message was:
      Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here is my class:

```
public class StorageService : IStorageService
{
    public StorageService()
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.AppSettings().Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.Loggly(
            logglyConfig: new LogglyConfiguration
            {
                //Log Config is here
            }).CreateLogger();
    }

    public async Task<bool> CreateTableIfNotExistsAsync(string storageConnectionString, string tableName)
    {
        // Some code here

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is my Test Case:

```
[Test]
public void create_storage()
{
    FakedStorageService = A.Fake<StorageService>(); // It is failing at this line
    // Some FakeCalls here
}
```

Comment: Surely you want a fake `IStorageService`, not a fake `StorageService`?

Comment: Thanks @John, that definitely did the trick! :)

Comment: Do you mind providing it as an answer? Thus I can mark as such. @John

Comment: Glad that was all you needed. I've added the answer as requested. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the issue is down to you trying to create a fake of the implementation instead of the interface. You can modify it to this:

```
FakedStorageService = A.Fake<IStorageService>();
```